# Error cannot find symbol- Java class and methods

Tags: java, class, methods

What's up guys,
I keep receiving this error, cannot find symbol  `Circle aCircle = new Circle();` , when trying to compile the driver code my professor gave us. I'm wondering if it is because I haven't added it to my circle.java method. This is the circle driver.

```
package lab7;

public class CircleDriver {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            Circle aCircle = new Circle();

            aCircle.setColor("green");
            aCircle.setRadius(10);
            aCircle.display();

            Double circleArea = aCircle.computeArea();
            Double circumference = aCircle.computeCircumference();

            System.out.println("circle area: " + circleArea);
            System.out.println("circle circumference: " + circumference);
            System.out.println();
          }

}
```

This is my circle method.`

```
public class Circle {

    private String color;
    private int radius;

    public Circle(String color, int radius) {
        this.color = color;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Circle() {
     Circle aCircle = new Circle();

    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("I am a circle");
        System.out.println("My color is " + color);
        System.out.println("My radius is " + radius);
    }

    public double computeArea() {
        return (Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2));
    }

    public double computeCircumference() {
        return (2 * Math.PI * radius);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are CircleDriver and Cricle in the same package? If not, are you importing Circle to CircleDriver?

Comment: My professor wants us to run the CircleDriver and so that it runs circle to figure out the area and circumference. Sorry if I made that unclear

Comment: Check that the classes are in the same package space. If not, you're going to need to import your Circle class into the CircleDriver class for use: `import full.qualified.path.to.Circle;`

Oh, and you don't need that empty constructor in Circle that instantiates another Circle. That's potentially going to cause a StackOverflow exception.

Comment: You could just instantiate your Circle object like this: `Circle circle = new Circle("green", 10);`. This means you don't need to explicitly set the color and radius on the Circle object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call a super() constructor when calling a circle. When you call

```
Circle aCircle = new Circle();
```

You are trying to initialize a circle in the local aspect. I think you are trying to inherit the Circle class that is already in java.

Leaving the circle constructor as

```
public Circle() {}
```

Should theoretically work to instantiate your class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. You have mistake in constructor. I hope it will solve your issue.

In **Circle.java**, instead of

```
public Circle() {
 Circle aCircle = new Circle();
}
```

Use this code

```
public Circle() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

**CircleDriver.java**

```
public class CircleDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle aCircle = new Circle();
        aCircle.setColor("green");
        aCircle.setRadius(10);
        aCircle.display();
        Double circleArea = aCircle.computeArea();
        Double circumference = aCircle.computeCircumference();
        System.out.println("circle area: " + circleArea);
        System.out.println("circle circumference: " + circumference);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Circle.java**

```
public class Circle {

    private String color;
    private int radius;

    public Circle() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Circle(String color, int radius) {
        super();
        this.color = color;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("I am a circle");
        System.out.println("My color is " + color);
        System.out.println("My radius is " + radius);
    }

    public double computeArea() {
        return (Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2));
    }

    public double computeCircumference() {
        return (2 * Math.PI * radius);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
I am a circle
My color is green
My radius is 10
circle area: 314.1592653589793
circle circumference: 62.83185307179586
```

Comment: @RahulSharma Nope, I have changed in constructor.

Comment: Anything for rep points, eh? This could have just been a comment,

Comment: What exactly does the super(); do?

Comment: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

Comment: @SkyWalker Thank you for that, when running the circledriver.java in cmd I get the same error... I'm using JavaC to compile it.

Comment: Thanks, it is running great.

Comment: @SebbyKurpiel http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/04/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-helloworld-java.html Follow the tutorial. If it helps, please accept the answer